# Symfony and Doctrine: How to turn a query with multiple sub selects into dql with joins

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need help with a query that is far beyond what I can manage. The query is supposed to give me a price for a package sent by a freighter. To get the price, it needs to check 7 tables for geographical zones, weight class and such. Here are the tables in sql:

The account table to get the prices for the selected freighter:

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

A price zone is to enable freighters to have the same price for several geo zones

```
CREATE TABLE `price_zone` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Geo zone is a zone that has a from and to zone

```
CREATE TABLE `geo_zone` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_zone_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_zone_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_zone_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_A4CCEF071972DC04` (`from_zone_id`),
  KEY `IDX_A4CCEF0711B4025E` (`to_zone_id`),
  KEY `IDX_A4CCEF07F40AF7F7` (`price_zone_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_A4CCEF0711B4025E` FOREIGN KEY (`to_zone_id`) REFERENCES `zone` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_A4CCEF071972DC04` FOREIGN KEY (`from_zone_id`) REFERENCES `zone` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_A4CCEF07F40AF7F7` FOREIGN KEY (`price_zone_id`) REFERENCES `price_zone` (`id`)
);
```

A zone is a collection of postal codes

```
CREATE TABLE `zone` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

A postal code is connected to the freighter account

```
CREATE TABLE `postal_code` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zone_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_EA98E3769F2C3FAB` (`zone_id`),
  KEY `IDX_EA98E3769B6B5FBA` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EA98E3769B6B5FBA` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EA98E3769F2C3FAB` FOREIGN KEY (`zone_id`) REFERENCES `zone` (`id`)
);
```

A package type is either a pallet, a box or similar. It is system wide, and not freighter specific

```
CREATE TABLE `package_type` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_length` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_width` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_height` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

A weight class is a freighters definition of min and max weight for boxes

```
CREATE TABLE `weight_class` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_weight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_weight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_D2EC4C2F9B6B5FBA` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D2EC4C2F9B6B5FBA` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`)
);
```

And finally a price table that connects everything together

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `package_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight_class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_zone_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_CAC822D94A17E91F` (`package_type_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CAC822D9A0206A65` (`weight_class_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CAC822D9F40AF7F7` (`price_zone_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAC822D94A17E91F` FOREIGN KEY (`package_type_id`) REFERENCES `package_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAC822D9A0206A65` FOREIGN KEY (`weight_class_id`) REFERENCES `weight_class` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAC822D9F40AF7F7` FOREIGN KEY (`price_zone_id`) REFERENCES `price_zone` (`id`)
);
```

A have a query that works, but I have the feeling that a SQL-savvy person is on its way to wack me on the head.

```
select p.price from price as p
where package_type_id = :packageType
and weight_class_id = (select id from weight_class where min_weight < :weight and max_weight > :weight)
and price_zone_id = (
    select price_zone_id from geo_zone
    where from_zone_id = (select zone_id from postal_code where account_id = :freighter and postal_code = :from)
    and to_zone_id = (select zone_id from postal_code where account_id = :freighter and postal_code = :to)
```

How on earth can this be done in symfony and doctrine with the `querybuilder`?

Thank you for reading through the whole question!

Regards,
Tommy

Comment: Just an opinion: You don't really need Doctrine for everything. SQL would be sufficient. Unless you really need objects returned in result. Btw: the querybuilder does not support sub-queries. Not sure about DQL though.

Comment: Thank you @ĐuroMandinić, I could possibly use the `prepare` function and rund the sql as is, but how would I bind parameters to a symfony `prepare` statement? The query only returns one integer value: the price. Or nothing.

Comment: Binding parameters is well documented: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements. A side note, very good video: https://youtu.be/rzGeNYC3oz0

Comment: Thank you again, that video was interesting (so far), I will finish it later today. The binding of parameters, it turns out, was correct, the problem was how I sent it from the front-end. So I will just use the sql as it is, although it feels icky with all the sub selects.